# upload videos on google drive and make them public from website

Tags: google-drive-api

I want to upload videos directly from website to google drive or picasa or any free google service, make it public and get its link on my web, is it possible with google drive api ?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? Did you take a look at the youtube api? That seems to be the place to store videos. Referencing Picasa does not help, that service has been discontinued: https://picasa.google.com/

Comment: I can upload video on google images and get it's lhe.googleusercontent.com link and paste it on my website. I want to make it directly from my website woth api